# how to arrange views inside coordinatorlayout?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

My `collapsible toolbar` works but covers the title as i was trying to scroll up using a `nestedscrollview`. I tried putting it inside relative layout but then the `toolbar` stopped working and wouldn't collapse anymore.

Here's my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context="com.store.android.basic.Introduction">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/introduction_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/app_toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id = "@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/heading"
                android:textColor="#D31F33"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id = "@+id/sub_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/text_one"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Just put this line in your NestedScrollView.